# Finding Frequency of Text Answers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have something similar to the included sheet:

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A, C | E, F | K |
| B | G, H | J, K |
| A, D | G, E | I, J |
| B, C | E, F | I, J, K |

Each column is a different question.  The students can give one or more answers; these are comma-separated.

How do I list the answers and the frequency of each answer for each column in the same sheet?  I have about a dozen sheets with the same layout.

At first, I looked at the =UNIQUE formula to break them up, but that won't work with multiple values in the same cell.  =FREQUENCY also won't work.

Edit: I neglected to show that each question has different answers.  I am changing the example to reflect that better.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is do-able with a query(split(flatten( type solution. See the picture below with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REDUCE({"",""},C2:E5,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(c,-ROW(c)+1,0)&"|"&SPLIT(c,", ",0)),"|",0,0)})),"select Col1,COUNT(Col1) where Col2<>'' group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That gives me a starting point.  However, I had neglected to show that each question had different answers.  The example is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another approach to try with the new sample:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE({"Question","Answer"},A2:C,LAMBDA(a,v,
IF(v="",a,VSTACK(a,REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SPLIT(v,", "),LAMBDA(b,t,
VSTACK(b,HSTACK(INDEX(1:1,COLUMN(v)),t)
))))))),
"SELECT Col1,Col2,COUNT(Col1) group by Col1,Col2
LABEL COUNT(Col1) 'Quantity'",1)
```

[image]